# "Unexpected error while acquiring application default credentials" from code in containers on GCP instances with authorized service account

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-iam

I had expected that containers running on an authorized GCP host using a service account, will have the same service account permissions that the host has. But this does not seem to be the case. My application that throws this exception is a node application using the pubsub and KMS APIs.

I understand that I can use GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS etc but I do not want to do that, I want to rely on the service account permissions.

I saw that with a "Ubuntu 18.04 LTS minimal" host and a "Ubuntu 16.04" based container. I do not think I had seen it ever before using 18.04

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the assumption is correct but the way some runtimes get the access token is that they query the metadata server at metadata.google.internal. This normally resolves to the address 169.254.169.254 but inside the container the address was not getting resolved.

The workaround was to add this argument when you start your container:

```
docker run ... --add-host=metadata.google.internal:169.254.169.254 ...
```